# Parsing log file with logs of different patterns Logstash

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, kibana-5

I am new to logstash in that matter ELK stack. A log file is having different processes logging data to it. Each process writes logs with different patterns. I want to parse this log file. Each log in this log file is started with below grok pattern,

> %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:logsource} %{SYSLOGPROG}: +
>   %{SRCFILE:srcfile}:%{NUMBER:linenumber} where SRCFILE is defined as
>   [a-zA-Z0-9._-]+

Please let me know how can I parse this file so that different type of logs from each process logging in this file can be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to pass in *log files*, you might have to use the [file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file) input plugin in order to retrieve a file or x number of files from a given path. So a basic `input` could look something like this:

```
input {

        file {
            path => "/your/path/*"
            exclude => "*.gz"
            start_position => "beginning" 
            ignore_older => 0 
            sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
}
```

The above is just a sample for you to reproduce. So once you get the files and start processing them line by line, you could use the [grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok) filter in order to match the keywords from your log file. A sample filter could look something like this:

```
grok {
    patterns_dir => ["/pathto/patterns"]
    match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:logsource} %{SYSLOGPROG}: + %{SRCFILE:srcfile}:%{NUMBER:linenumber} where SRCFILE is defined as [a-zA-Z0-9._-]+" }           
}
```

You might have to use different filters if you're having different type of logs printed within a single file **OR** you could have it in the same line with a `,` comma separated values. Something like:

```
grok {
        match => { "message" => [ 
              "TYPE1,%{WORD:a1},%{WORD:a2},%{WORD:a3},%{POSINT:a4}",
              "TYPE2,%{WORD:b1},%{WORD:b2},%{WORD:b3},%{WORD:b4}",
              "TYPE3,%{POSINT:c1},%{WORD:c2},%{POSINT:c3},%{WORD:c4}"  ]
        }
    }
```

And then maybe you could play around with the `message`, since you've got all the values you needed right within it. Hope it helps!